# Generic OnChange Function for Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple select elements that need to execute a javascript function when changed. I would like to make a generic function, so I can set multiple onchange methods to this same function.

This works and does exactly what I want:

```
myselect.onchange = function() {
   *some code*
}
```

However, using the exact same code but using a named function declared outside of the onchange event as follows, does not:

```
function myfunc(){
   *some code*
}

myselect.onchange = myfunc();
```

How can I create a named function and set my onchange methods to it? Is this possible? There is so much repeated code otherwise :(

EDIT:
In my example I didn't have my function accepting parameters. To make this useful for my multiple selects I need to pass it a parameter. Without using parenthesis how can I do that?

Comment: remove parentheses that is `myselect.onchange = myfunc;`

Comment: wow, well don't I feel stupid. It works! Thanks man! If you make that an answer I will make is as the solution. Man, I fought with that for hours!

Comment: realized there is still an issue, please see my edit

Comment: See my update. You will like it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the expression `myselect.onchange = myfunc;` right side must be `Function` object.
It is OK to write `myselect.onchange = myfunc('something');` provided `myfunc` returns `function`. Something like this.

```js
var select1 = document.getElementById('sel1');
var select2 = document.getElementById('sel2');
select1.onchange = myfunc('Hello ');
select2.onchange = myfunc('Good Bye ');

function myfunc(greet) {
  return function() {
    console.log(greet + this.value);
  };
}
```

```html
<select id="sel1">
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
</select>
<select id="sel2">
  <option>Three</option>
  <option>Four</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT:** As `Function`s are First-class objects they can be function *parameters*. Something like this.

```js
var select1 = document.getElementById('sel1');
var select2 = document.getElementById('sel2');
select1.onchange = myfunc(foo);
select2.onchange = myfunc(bar);

function myfunc(callback) {
  return function() {
    callback(this.value);
  };
}

function foo(val) {
  console.log('Hello from foo ' + val);
}

function bar(val) {
  console.log('Hello from bar ' + val);
}
```

```html
<select id="sel1">
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
</select>
<select id="sel2">
  <option>Three</option>
  <option>Four</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions in javascript are actually first class citizens, which means they **can be assigned to variables, can be passed around as arguments, and can even be assigned as return values of other functions**.

So when you do:

```
myselect.onchange = myfunc();
```

You are setting the onchange property of `myselect` to hold the return values of `myfunc` itself.

When you do:

```
myselect.onchange = myfunc;
```

You are setting the onchange property of `myselect` to reference the `myfunc` function itself.

To answer your latest edit to the post, you can add arguments to the function when you first declared it, and still pass your function around. For example:

```
myfunc(arg1, arg2) {
  *some code*
}

myselect.onchange = myfunc;
```

Comment: thank you for your explanation, but how do I then pass "myfunc" the parameters I need for each different onchange?

Comment: To clarify, I obviously need to set arg1 and arg2 a certain value which will be different for each instance of a select where I set my onchange = myfunc. I don't see  how I set them. Sorry I am obviously not that well verse in javascript :)

Comment: What is myselect and what do you intend to achieve? Could you show me a sample of your code?